# Is the maximum work done by voltaic cell per mole of reaction?

Tags: thermodynamics, electrochemistry, free-energy

From the equation $w_{elec,rev}=-nF\Delta E$, and n = the number of moles of electrons transferred in the overall redox reaction, does that make the work per mole of the redox reaction? I am confused because one mole of reaction does not necessarily happen, so how does w and ∆G adjust to account for fewer/more moles of electrons being transferred. Is this perhaps just a convention?

Comment: $W_\mathrm{m}=q_\mathrm{m} \Delta E=nF\Delta E$ and   $\Delta G_\mathrm{m} = -W_\mathrm{m} =-nF\Delta E$

Comment: Note that n is not the molar amount of electrons (We do not say number of kilograms either.), but literally the number of electrons exchanged with 1 particle (molecule/ion), so nF is the charge exchanged with 1 mol of electroactive particles. By dimension analysis, n is unitless and w has unit J/mol. // If we insist on n as molar amount of electrons than w has unit J, not J/mol.